# Is it possible to dynamicly exclude Features or Product Options

Tags: cpq

This is my first exposure to Salesforce CPQ, and I'm trying to find a way to only show features for specific Customers.  We have a line of products that should only be available to Customers in the Healthcare Industry.

Product Model:

```
Base Option <- available to everyone
|-> Healthcare Feature <- Only needs to be seen by healthcare
      |-> healthcare option <- Product only applies to healthcare industry
```

Is there a native way to show the healthcare feature and/or healthcare options only to healthcare customers, while still leaving the Base Option available to everyone?

Answer (score 0):

you can create [product rule](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cpq_selection_rules.htm&type=0) that will run on load or configure of a bundle and hide or show the options  on the basis of certain criteria

Although feature cannot be hidden, in case if the feature has all options hidden then the Feature will show up with message "No visible options"

Right now there is no way to not render options dynamically , you can upvote this idea for the same https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E5A1QAK